# Are there grants available to pay for travel to my PhD program?

Tags: phd, funding, travel

I have looked at this [travel grant question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/897/travel-grants-for-international-students-in-the-us) but it talks about when the OP already was pursuing his PhD.

I am from India and have a different scenario as I have just received my PhD offer in Computer Science. Are there institutions that can fund my going there (even just the flight)? I do have good academic records as well as papers published.

I have searched on the internet and have found one from [tata](http://www.srtt.org/individual_grants/education_grants.htm). But, Are you aware of any others that do provide support?

Comment: Will your phd be funded by the school? Have you checked with your department to see if they can cover some of your relocation expenses?

Answer (score 5):

I am not aware of any relocation only independent grants, but there are a number of other ways relocation expenses could be covered. There may be funding available via the University, Department, or PI. If you are being funded by an external grant relocation 
expenses may be allowable (e.g., the [NIH](http://grants.nih.gov/grants/policy/nihgps_2011/nihgps_ch7.htm#preaward_preagreement_costs) allows relocation costs).

Answer (score 3):

If you have already been in contact with your future (potential) advisor, you might raise the issue with them.  They might have funding they can use, or (more likely) they might be able to pull strings with the department or university to provide travel funding.

However, I do *not* recommend raising this issue as your *first* contact with a potential advisor.